# Jmeter - find with regex and replace part of XML body using groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to replace part an XML response data with something else.
Here is an example:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trustedDevices><trustedDevice><id>1942</id><name>BksQ9LKwWuNOHpn</name></trustedDevice><trustedDevice><id>1944</id><name>6f4srs4PkJk1j36</name></trustedDevice><trustedDevice><id>1943</id><name>7cGYVAlmQoXaVrf</name></trustedDevice></trustedDevices>
```

I'm trying to get all the `<name>(.+?)<\/name>` data and replace it with something else (timestamp or random string)

so far, my groovy post processor code looks like this:

```
String trustedDevices = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

log.info('Response: ' + trustedDevices)
def nameFind = "/<name>(.+?)<\/name>/"
def newTrustedDevices = trustedDevices.replaceAll(nameFind, "test")

log.info('New response: ' + newTrustedDevices)
```

Unfortunately it seems that `replaceAll` requires String or Long to work, and won't work with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex just need a correct escaping:

```
def nameFind = "<name>(.+?)<\\/name>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Replacing values in XML using regular expressions is not the best option as it will be fragile and very sensitive to any markup change.

I would suggest going for [Groovy's XML parsing capabilities](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) instead

Example code:

```
def trustedDevices = new XmlSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
trustedDevices.trustedDevice.findAll().each {
    it.name = 'test'
}
def newTrustedDevices = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield trustedDevices }.toString()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)